# Basic LINQ query to check if string occurs within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list MyGroups and a string 'AllowedGroups'.

For example I have string in MyGroups.Name = "Admin Only" and AllowedGroups ="Admin Only, Normal Group".
I can't understand why the following expression evaluates to false when it should be true:

```
model.MyGroups.Any(m => m.Name.Contains(AllowedGroups)
```

Comment: you are thinking of it backwards.

Comment: `AllowedGroups` _should_ be a list or other collection... just saying.

Comment: To clarify @Daniel's comment: you're doing `"Admin Only".Contains("Admin Only, Normal Group")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need, based on the information you've provided, is the opposite of what you have.

Something like this:

```
var allowedGroupsArray = AllowedGroups.Split(',');
var result = model.MyGroups.Any(m => allowedGroupsArray.Contains(m.Name));
```

Specifically, using `Array.Contains()` inside the `.Any()` call should generate basically a `WHERE ... IN` type clause in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

it returns false because Admin Only does not contain Admin Only, Normal Group

Comment: This answer popped up in the Low Quality Posts review queue. I think I see what you're going for, but I think some formatting would help illustrate what you're trying to convey.